# How can I remove a abnormal hidden character in windows-10 security tab in C#

Tags: c#, windows, unicode, windows-10, filepath

I found out a hidden charactor in the path of the windows-10 security tab.

1. in Windows 10, Right-click -> Property
2. on the Security tab, highlight the full path of "Object name".
3. copy and paste into notepad++ in ANSI encoding.
4. It is supposed to be **"‪C:\Users\Mark\Documents"** but it shows with one additional charactor like **"?C:\Users\Mark\Documents"**

I tried to search this in the Unicode map but could not find what is this about.
Does anyone happen to know what is this character from?
Please find attachment here for your understanding:
https://go.aws/2NsPQrk
(I cannot upload a picture directly due to my workplace's policy.)

Comment: Converting Unicode to ANSI is a lossy operation. If you wish to analyze this, use a Unicode-aware editor.

Comment: SuperUser or security StackExchange sister sites are probably more appropriate. Maybe it is just a common error on windows (a BOM?), maybe between different versions, or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING(U+202A) in unicode.

unicode inspection : https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%E2%80%AAC%3A%5CUsers%5CMark%5CDocuments#block-U2000

Unicode detail : https://unicode-table.com/en/202A/

Here is the way I inspect in C#:

```
Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
String line = Console.ReadLine(); // enter the copied path. 
string u202 = "\u202A";
if(line.Contains(u202))
    Console.WriteLine("matched.");
```

To remove it:

```
line= line.Replace(u202, String.Empty);
```

To write a validation code whether its a right path:

```
bool isWrong = line.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) == -1;
```

Comment: @MrLister I've just edited it.